How to fill and center HorizontalStackLayout
I have a problem, I have a few buttons and want to center them in a HorizontalStackLayout. I like this HorizontalStackLayout to expand from the left to right side of the window to have the visual appearance I want.
In this case, by choosing HorizontalOptions I can make it from side to side or centered. I can not make it both. Does anyone have some idea how to fix that?
Case with HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"

Case with HorizontalOptions="Fill"

code:
<HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="20" HorizontalOptions="Fill" x:DataType="local:MainPageViewModel" Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Blue">
    <HorizontalStackLayout.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="60"/>
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ChangeDateOfWeekCommand}"/>
        </Style>
    </HorizontalStackLayout.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label>date</Label>
        <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference MondayButton}}" x:Name="MondayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Pon" ></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference TuesdayButton}}" x:Name="TuesdayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Wt"></Button>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference WednesdayButton}}" x:Name="WednesdayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Śr"></Button>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference ThursdayButton}}" x:Name="ThursdayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Czw"></Button>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference FridayButton}}" x:Name="FridayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Pt"></Button>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SobButton}}" x:Name="SobButton" TextColor="Red" Text="Sob"></Button>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SaturdayButton}}" x:Name="SaturdayButton" TextColor="Red" Text="Nd"></Button>
</HorizontalStackLayout>

I want buttons to be centered and HorizontalStackLayout to be filling a Grid.Row

The *AndExpand layout options are deprecated in MAUI and are without function. They only still exist for compatibility reasons and will eventually be removed altogether.

"Centering" implies a "parent". If it is your wish to "center" your panel, and have the "sides" filled (with color), then you should be looking at the "parent's" background color.  i.e. the parts not overlapped in the parent. ("stack panels", in general, don't "stretch" beyond their content. I repeat, "in general".)

You may try using FlexLayout to distribute the space evenly around each button.
You may try the following way to use a FlexLayout,
<FlexLayout Direction="Row"  JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  x:DataType="local:MainPageViewModel"   Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Blue">
    <FlexLayout.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            ......
        </Style>
    </FlexLayout.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label>date</Label>
        <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference MondayButton}}" x:Name="MondayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Pon" ></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <Button Pressed="ChangeButtonBackgroundOnPress" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference TuesdayButton}}" x:Name="TuesdayButton" TextColor="White" Text="Wt"></Button>
    ......
</FlexLayout>


Here is the screenshot,


If your plan is to place the HorizontalStacklayout inside a grid, it is always better to place the buttons directly in grid columns and rows. I know this is more work, but better for performance as you decrease the depth of your visual tree. If you still want to use the HorizontalStacklayout you can set VerticalOptions="Center" on each Button. That should center them.
